# Why do I get an error when importing metrics from Open Telemetry?

Tags: python, open-telemetry

```py
import time    
from opentelemetry import metrics
```

Error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'metrics' from 'opentelemetry' (unknown location)
```

I can import `trace` but I cannot import `metrics`.

How to import `metrics` from `opentelemetry`?